# How to remove/replace hyphens in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this set of data that contains hyphens sign in my cell. My plan is to replace this hyphens sign to a number of 0 so that I can convert my column to numeric data type to do a calculation. The tricky part is where I only need to replace the cell that only contains hyphens sign (row 2 and row 3) without changing the negative value (row 6,7,8 and 9). I tried to use

```
regexp_replace("M1KW",'-','0','g')
```

function but it does change the negative value as well.
Any other special command that I can use ?

This is my sample data:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Please edit your question to include data as plain text formatted as a table instead of a link to an image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to treat the string `'-'` as `'0'`.  If so, you can directly replace the values:

```
update t
    set mikw = '0'
    where mikw = '-';
```

Answer (score 1):

> so that I can convert my column to numeric data type to do a calculation

You don't need to UPDATE all rows before being able to convert the data type to the correct one:

```
alter table the_table
   alter mikw type numeric 
   using (case when mikw = '-' then 0 else mikw::numeric end);
```

That will do the "update" and the change of the data type in a single operation, rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the RIGHT function would be useful here, for isolating only instances where the hyphen is the last character.

Try this out:

```
    UPDATE your_table 
    SET M1KW = 0
    WHERE RIGHT(M1KW, 1) = '-';
```